# Vector Sum of Pythagorean Triples

Tags: number-theory, algebra

Given any finite set of linearly independent Pythagorean Triples, show that the vector sum of this set is never a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: Would this be better posted on the [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) instead of Puzzling?

Comment: Ok. Boundaries are fuzzy.

Comment: [Math puzzles are welcome here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7200/69582) as long as they are [puzzles, not problems](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/69582). See links for details. I don't know enough to determine which side of the line this falls on, but if it's on-topic here then it's on-topic here, regardless if there's another site which would also take it.

Comment: This is puzzle / problem that I made up. Thought it was cool / fun.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The graph of real-valued Pythagorean triples $x^2+y^2=z^2$ forms an infinite cone if we restrict to $z>0$:

[image: Double cone]

A sum of $n$ independent vectors on this cone is $n$ times their average, which lies within their convex hull and so is inside the cone, and so cannot be a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: this is insanely neat - i agree now that it's well-suited for Puzzling!

Answer (score 5):

By definition of (Euclidean) length, 2-dimensional vector $v_j:=(a_j,b_j)$ has length $|v_j|=c_j$ if and only if $a_j^2+b_j^2=c_j^2$ ($c_j\ge 0$). By repeated application of the

> triangle inequality

we have for any finite sum $\left|\sum_j v_j\right| \le \sum_j c_j$ with equality if and only if each $v_j$ is a nonnegative multiple of every other nonzero $v_j$. As the given vectors are assumed to be linearly independent the inequality must be strict. In particular, the sums do not form a Pythagorean triple.